# How can I amplify a square wave signal with a mosfet?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, instrumentation-amplifier

I have a CCD camera that is triggered by an external TTL square wave.
That is each time the camera sees a rising edge on the square wave it takes a picture.
The square wave is being output from a custom microcontroller card when in capture mode.
So far I have used a oscilloscope to verify that the microcontroller card is indeed in capture mode and outputing a square wave.

I want to create a small circuit where a LED is being controlled by the square wave signal (0->5V).
That way I can instantly see if the camera is running or not.

I do not want to draw much current from the signal. I have some 2N700 mosfets. So I want to use one of these to amplify the signal.

This is what I have come up with so far:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbL64D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Should this work?
Is there some easy way (eg. change resistances, I have a wide range of resistances) to improve the design?

BTW the input impedance of my oscilloscope is 200k Ohms. Maybe the input impedance of my circuit should be in this ballpark?

I have tested the circuit with a function generator as input and it appears to work just fine.
However when I use it on the real signal it blinks as expected for a while and then get stuck in high state for a while and then blinks again. The stuck in high state is not something I expected. Not sure if this is a problem with my circuit or the software running on the custom microcontroller card.

May it suffice to drive the led directly from the signal:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpgKCQ.png)</sup>

This should draw 5.5 mA from the output of the microcontroller.
Would that be a problem?

Comment: The uC can drive the R to LED directly. You do not need anything else. Just choose hi or lo side for power ON and use 1k for low current

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75: thank you for your help. I am not sure I understand your suggestion though. In particular I do not understand "hi or lo side". Are you talking about connecting a led in series with a 1k Ohm resistor and run the signal trough this? Will this not cause the led to "float"?

Comment: No. R to cathode and. +V to anode is low side drive. Low =On

Comment: 5V uC have 50 ohm drivers

Comment: Is my last simplified circuit correct?

Comment: yes , that's positive logic or high side driver for indicator

Comment: I measured 2.9 mA for green led and 3.15 mA for red led using a function generator as input. My MCU is STM32F071. In general a pin can source 25mA however it is stated: " PC13, PC14 and PC15 are supplied through the power switch. Since the switch only sinks a limited amount of current
(3 mA), the use of GPIOs PC13 to PC15 in output mode is limited:
- The speed should not exceed 2 MHz with a maximum load of 30 pF.
- These GPIOs must not be used as current sources (e.g. to drive an LED)." Maybe I should use a 1.5k resistor?

Comment: 2mA or 10% is recommended minimum

Comment: Is any of PC13, PC14, or PC15 the pin you use to trigger the CCD? If not, that note does not apply. -- If you see the LED stuck for a while, what does your oscilloscope measure at the same time?